# How to redirect to previous page after saving post data and show that data in the previous page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Page 1 had a button. When user click on he can see a form which will ask to fill amount and share details. Once he submitted the data will get saved into database. Once the data saved to database i want to redirect to previous page (the page where i clicked the button to see form). And in that page when i redirects in place of button i want to show the amount which eh saved in the database.

Any ideas how to do this thing efficiently.

Comment: if u use java script use window.history.back(); or window.history.go(-1) or if referrer page is same all the time then use php header function to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in `$_SESSION` on DB insert and then on the order page check if session exist with that specific name and if not show button ,else show quantity,price or whatever on redirect to that page

Answer (score 0):

Page1.php

```
if ($_GET['details']=="true") {
  //print details
} else {
  //print button
}
```

postpage.php

```
//handle database
header('Location: page1.php?details=true');
```

Comment: Hugo i am able to redirect it using Javascript but the problem is how can i get post data in previous page..

Comment: you could use a <form onsubmit="redirectme(this)"> and then in the redirectme function get the values from all input fields. You can then pass it along with the redirect.

Comment: I am able to redirect it. Thats not a problem.........Now how i need to get that post data from the form in place of button in main page

Comment: You are posting what is in a form. eg <input name='name' id='name'>. now in the redirectme method you can use window.location.href='page1.php?name='+document.getElementById('name');

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Note that this may not work with secure pages (HTTPS) and it's a pretty bad idea overall as the header can be hijacked, sending the user to some other destination. The header may not even be sent by the browser.

you can store the data in `$_SESSION` Values

Answer (score 0):

Load Codeigniter's URL Helper by either calling:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Or in edit your `application/config/autoload.php` file and auto load it:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

After the data is successfully stored in the database just use:

> redirect('/CONTROLLER_NAME_HERE/METHOD_NAME_HERE/', 'refresh');

Check url helper documentation here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html